# Pass parameters to Django class meta

Tags: django, class, python-2.7, parameters, django-forms

I am trying to display a form with Django, but I want to remove a field if the user language is 'en'. I would like to avoid doing it in Javascript or doing a second template just for it. So I wonder if it possible to pass parameter to the `Meta()` class of my `UserForm()` class. That way I could pass the user and check with an `if` statement his language.

Here is what I have so far:

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(required=True, label=_('*First name'))
    last_name = forms.CharField(required=True, label=_('*Last name'))
    postal_code = FRZipCodeField(required=False, label=_('My postcode'))
    birthday = forms.DateField(
        widget=forms.DateInput(format='%d/%m/%Y'),
        required=False,
        input_formats=['%d/%m/%Y'],
        label=_('My birthday'))

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Field('gender'),
            Field('first_name'),
            Field('last_name'),
            Field('birthday'),
            Field('country'),
            Field('language'),
            Field('payment_preference'),
            Div('addr1', css_class='hidden', css_id='addr1_container'),
            Div('addr2', css_class='hidden', css_id='addr2_container'),
            Div('addr3', css_class='hidden', css_id='addr3_container'),
            Div('postal_code', css_class='hidden', css_id='pc_container'),
            Div('city', css_class='hidden', css_id='city_container'),                                                                                    
            ButtonHolder(
                Submit('save', _('update'), css_class='pull-right'),
            )
        )

    class Meta():
        model = User

        fields = (
            "first_name", "last_name", "gender", "birthday", "country",
            "payment_preference", "addr1", "addr2", "addr3", "postal_code",
            "city", "language",)
```

With an if, I could set two different fields variable in the Meta() class and so show two different forms for each user language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass it into the Meta, but you can pass it into the `__init__` and hide the field you want to hide:

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # ... as before
    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if user.language == 'en':
            self.fields['field_name'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
    # ... as before
```

Then when you call the form, pass the user as the first argument:

```
form = UserForm(request.user, ...)
```